# SpringBoot with Swagger redirecting wrongly

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, reverse-proxy, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using Swagger with a SpringBoot project, behind a reverse proxy. When I try to access `https://localhost:8080/api`, instead of redirecting me to `https://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui/index.html`, it redirects me to `https://<my computer host in the network>:8081/api/swagger-ui/index`. However, when I access `https://localhost:8080/api/` (note the trailing `/`), it works perfectly as intended.

I When I execute a `curl -v -k https://localhost:8080/api` I get the following output:

```
> GET /api HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
```

And

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Location: https://<my computer host in the network>:8081/api/
< Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2023 09:32:01 GMT
```

I am assuming SpringBoot is redirecting things wrong somewhere. I just can't figure out where.